# javascript (safari) - 'undefined' is not a function evaluating elm.parentNode.remove(elm)

Tags: javascript, safari

So this little chunk of js works fine in every other browser except safari.  Its really simple.  Heres my HTML:

```
<div>
<input type="text" class="input_l" name="location[]" />
<a onclick="closeLocation(this)">Remove</a>
</div>
```

the js is:

```
function closeLocation(elm){
    elm.parentNode.remove(elm);
}
```

basically when I click 'remove' I want its parent div removed with everything in it.  AGAIN it works fine in every browser except safari here is the error:

```
'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'elm.parentNode.remove(elm)')
```

Im not sure whats going on, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [**Node.removeChild**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Node.removeChild)

```
 elm.parentNode.removeChild(elm);
```

**when I click 'remove' I want its parent div removed with everything in it**

As per your requirement you need to use

```
 elm.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(elm.parentNode);
```

Comment: Sweet, that worked!! you are gentleman and a scholar good sir! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
elm.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(elm.parentNode);
```

Comment: Thanks for posting.  I tried that, it only removes the <a> tag, not the parent.